# LEFT JOIN not returning desired results

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join, ssms

I have two queries, and output is as shown below for each of the queries:

```
SELECT UserID, ActivityDate, ActivityDay, ActivityTime
FROM Activities 
WHERE ActivityType='MYS'
```

[image]

```
SELECT USerID, TimeFrom, TimeTo, ActivityDay
FROM [dbo].[userActivities]  WHERE UserID=123
```

[image]

**Expected Result:**

Both queries can be linked using the following:

- Activities.UserID = userActivities.UserID
- Activities.ActivityDay = userActivities.ActivityDay

I need to have all 4 rows from the first dataset, and the new columns that needs be added is based on values in the second query. There are two records for ActvityDay 7 because there are two records in the next query for ActvityDay 7

[image]

I was trying to extract the data using `LEFT JOIN` but was not getting the desired result. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Query I'm trying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AD.UserID, AD.ActiityDate, AD.ActivityDay, AD.ActivityTime,
CASE WHEN AD.ActiityDate = userActivities.ActivityDay THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [ActivityExists],
CASE WHEN AD.ActiityDate = userActivities.ActivityDay THEN UA.TimeFrom ELSE '' END AS [Time],
FROM Activities AD LEFT JOIN userActivities UA ON AD.UserID=UA.UserID 
AND AD.ActiityDate = userActivities.ActivityDay
```

Comment: `ActivityDate` and `ActivityDay` do not appear to lend themselves to direct comparison. Semi-related, you should just be able to use `UA.UserID IS NULL` for the first case's condition.

Comment: Please don't use images, format the data as text.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. Isolate the first unexpected subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

You base your joins and the CASE expressions on wrong columns.
Also since you use aliases for the tables use the aliases and don't mix table names and aliases.
Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  AD.UserID, AD.ActivityDate, AD.ActivityDay, AD.ActivityTime,
  CASE WHEN AD.ActivityDay = UA.ActivityDay THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [ActivityExists],
  CASE WHEN AD.ActivityDay = UA.ActivityDay THEN UA.TimeFrom ELSE '' END AS [Time]
FROM Activities AD LEFT JOIN userActivities UA 
ON AD.UserID=UA.UserID  AND AD.ActivityDay = UA.ActivityDay
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=439df5c3713f88233b4c7679388de0ae).
Results:

```
> UserID | ActivityDate | ActivityDay | ActivityTime | ActivityExists | Time    
> -----: | :----------- | ----------: | :----------- | :------------- | :-------
>    123 | 2020-01-20   |           1 | 2:20 PM      | No             |         
>    123 | 2020-01-23   |           4 | 2:54 PM      | No             |         
>    123 | 2020-01-24   |           5 | 3:06 PM      | Yes            | 9:10 AM 
>    123 | 2020-01-28   |           7 | 11:00 AM     | Yes            | 11:15 AM
>    123 | 2020-01-28   |           7 | 11:00 AM     | Yes            | 12:05 PM
```